# how to split column after using union

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
select *
  from (select debit
          from tblarpayments a
         where     paymenttype = 6
               and credit = 0
               and checkid = 522
        union
        select credit
          from tblarpayments b
         where     paymenttype = 6
               and debit = 0
               and checkid = 522
        union
        select debit
          from tblarpayments c
         where     ref# like 'A/R%'
               and checkid = 522
        union
        select credit
          from tblarpayments d
         where     debit = 0
               and paymenttype = 2
               and checkid = 522
        union
        select debit
          from tblarpayments e
         where     credit = 0
               and ref# not like 'A/R%'
               and checkid = 522)
| |   DEBIT   |
|1| 10.0000   |
|2| 240.0000  |
|3| 250.0000  |
|4| 11540.0000|
```

I want it to be in 1 row 
Like this

```
 | |DEBIT     |CREDIT|DEBIT1 |CREDIT1 |DEBIT2  |
 |1|11540.0000|      |10.0000|250.0000|240.0000|
```

LOSS GAIN COMMISSION CREDIT DEBIT 
in second cell Credit has no value coz at checkid=522 debit = 0 paymenttype = 6 has no credit value it is null.
all in 1 row how can I solve it? I tried many things but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please take a few moments and format your code, by indenting each line by 4 spaces (or more).  Also, don't include links to data/images, instead include text directly in your question.

Comment: Switch from UNION to CROSS JOIN, or GROUP BY with conditional aggregation.

Comment: The output shown in the image does not match the query you've posted. So it's pretty hard for us to show how to rewrite the SELECT.

Comment: i looked up and fixed my output sorry i mixed my pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is a single matching row per condition then you can do it in a single table scan:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/978c88/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tblarpayments ( paymenttype, credit, debit, ref#, checkid ) AS
SELECT 6, 0, 123, NULL, 522 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 456, 0, NULL, 522 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, NULL, 789, 'A/R', 522 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 111, 0, NULL, 522 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 0, 222, 'X/Y', 522 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN ( paymenttype, credit ) IN ( ( 6, 0 ) ) THEN debit  END ) AS debit,
       MAX( CASE WHEN ( paymenttype, debit  ) IN ( ( 6, 0 ) ) THEN credit END ) AS credit,
       MAX( CASE WHEN ref# LIKE 'A/R%' THEN debit END ) AS debit1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN ( paymenttype, debit  ) IN ( ( 2, 0 ) ) THEN credit END ) AS credit1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN ref# NOT LIKE 'A/R%' AND credit = 0 THEN debit END ) AS debit2
FROM   tblarpayments
WHERE  (  ( paymenttype, credit ) IN ( ( 6, 0 ) )
       OR ( paymenttype, debit  ) IN ( ( 6, 0 ), ( 2, 0 ) )
       OR ref# LIKE 'A/R%'
       OR ( ref# NOT LIKE 'A/R%' AND credit = 0 )
       )
AND    checkid = 522
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/978c88/1/0)**:

```
| DEBIT | CREDIT | DEBIT1 | CREDIT1 | DEBIT2 |
|-------|--------|--------|---------|--------|
|   123 |    456 |    789 |     111 |    222 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each of your rows returns no more than one row then this will work for you:

```
select t1.debit as LOSS
       , t2.credit as GAIN 
       , t3.debit as COMMISSION 
       , t4.credit as CREDIT 
       , t5.debit as DEBIT   
from ( 
    select *
    from tblarpayments a
    where  checkid = 522
    and paymenttype = 6
    and credit = 0
) t1
left outer join ( 
    select *
    from tblarpayments a
    where  checkid = 522
    and  paymenttype = 6
    and debit = 0
) t2 on t1.checkid = t2.checkid
left outer join ( 
    select *
    from tblarpayments a
    where  checkid = 522
    and ref# like 'A/R%'
) t3 on t1.checkid = t3.checkid
left  outer join ( 
    select *
    from tblarpayments a
    where  checkid = 522
    and debit = 0
    and paymenttype = 2
) t4 on t1.checkid = t4.checkid
left outer join ( 
    select *
    from tblarpayments a
    where  checkid = 522
    and credit = 0
    and ref# not like 'A/R%'
) t5 on t1.checkid = t5.checkid
```

I've used LEFT OUTER JOINs on the assumption that you'll always have a LOSS record but you may not have all the records (you're image showed no value for GAIN). However, FULL OUTER JOIN may be more appropriate: you know your data and I don't. Alternatively, if you can guarantee that there will always be a record from each subquery then you should use INNER JOINs instead.

Note that if any of the subqueries does return more than one row you'll get a product, so you will have to adjust the filters accordingly.

---

There are probably more performative ways of writing this query. However, without actual table structures and representative data there's a limit to how much speculative code I'm going to write.